# Can someone explain the different types of unix domain sockets?

Tags: socket

If I run `netstat --all | grep ^unix` some of the socket paths that are outputted are preceded with a '@' and some aren't. I've noticed that those preceded with a '@' don't show up when browsing the file system with `ls` but the rest do.

What are these two kinds of sockets and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are [*abstract* sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), that live outside the filesystem namespace.  `netstat --unix`, `lsof -U` and other commands print an `@` sign instead of the nul byte that's at the start of the pathname.

Comment: What role do those *abstract sockets* play in general?

Comment: @Geek It's just a different namespace. There is no need for filesystem access and cleanup. On the other hand anyone can grab a well-known name, so you may have to check the credentials of the server process.